# How to p-value with uppercase letter P to a ggplot object by using stat_cor() function?

Tags: r, ggplot2, p-value

I created a scatterplot and trying to add R and P values on it. I used `stat_cor()` function of ggpubr package. That function allows you to use uppercase or lowercase R coefficient but I couldn't find an option for p-value. Is there a way to write letter p of p-value in uppercase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to create the label yourself using the computed variables (see `?stat_cor` returned by `stat_cor` and replacing the `p` with a `P` using e.g. `gsub`:

Making use of the default example from `?stat_cor`:

```r
library(ggpubr)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2

df <- mtcars
df$cyl <- as.factor(df$cyl)

sp <- ggscatter(df, x = "wt", y = "mpg",
                add = "reg.line",  # Add regressin line
                add.params = list(color = "blue", fill = "lightgray"), # Customize reg. line
                conf.int = TRUE # Add confidence interval
)
sp + stat_cor(aes(label = paste(..rr.label.., gsub("p", "P", ..p.label..), sep = "~`,`~")),
  label.x = 3
)
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]